# Java: Code with JButton and a timer works in some methods but not others

Tags: java, multithreading, button, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to create a program that moves a button to a random location after it is pressed. The player has to respond before a certain timeframe or the game goes to game over. The game works, but after there is game over, the button does not move back to the middle and the timer does not start back up. Game over is a method in my GUI class. Thank you in advance for any help!!!

```
public void gameOver() {
    System.out.println("Game Over (add pop-up) - You tapped " + taps + " times!");

    //RESET everything
    System.out.print("Started gameOver");

    timer.pause();
    taps = 0;
    tapHere.setBounds(305, 325, 90, 50);

    System.out.print("Finished gameOver");
}
```

Here is the Timer class code:

```
public class Timer extends GUI implements Runnable {

private int counter = 0;
Thread t = new Thread (this);
private volatile boolean isRunning = false;

public Timer() {}

public void run() {

    while (isRunning)
    {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(counter);
        if (counter >= 24)
        {
            gameOver();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}

public void start() {
    t.start();
}

public void pause() {
    isRunning = false;
    counter = 0;
}

public void time() {
    isRunning = true;
}
```

}

Full code is on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/r90AVHuW) and [Github](https://github.com/bfurman777/Tap-Fun-Java)

Comment: You need to call `revalidate()` on the panel your button is moving around on after setting the bounds. Also, don't post links to your code. Instead, create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates your problem.

Comment: @VinceEmigh `revalidate` will cause the container hierarcy to be re-laid out, since the OP seems to be using `setBounds`, which suggests they are using a `null` layout, that won't work